# Add Edit operation on Grocerycrud

Tags: grocery-crud

I've got a out-of-the-box installation of grocerycrud. The samples worked just fine. However, when I tested it with my own table with tinyint columns, it just don't work. The following is my schema:

```
role_id int(11) Auto Increment     role varchar(55)   
can_add tinyint(1) [0]     can_edit tinyint(1) [0]    
can_delete  tinyint(1) [0]
```

With this table, the tinyints are rendered as radio buttons. However, this causes the following errors as shown in chrome-dev console:

```
jquery.uniform.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined(anonymous function) @ jquery.uniform.min.js:1(anonymous function) @         
jquery.uniform.min.js:1
jquery.uniform.config.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).uniform is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, the trick was update jquery.uniform.min.js to  [version 2.2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AudithSoftworks/Uniform/2.2/dist/jquery.uniform.min.js), now it works again.